# Joomla log in denied

Tags: authentication

I have a website i'm working on in Joomla. I tried to log in to back end but now my username and password are not being accepted. tried to recover them but I get error message saying that my email isn't registered on system. I've tried all my emails that I have but not working. I cant find any support for this on the site. What do I do?

Comment: This is the wrong site for questions like this. SO is a platform for specfic programming issues. Please go to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thank you. I will head there now